# C++ error: 'inline' can only appear on functions

Tags: c++

So I'm stuck with one nasty issue and spent an hour already investigating.

I have a project with some rather old C++-ish code, and I need to add some C++11 code to it. The project was previously compiling, so it's quite certain that the issue was introduced by me adding the following to my CMakelist.txt:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

The problems are caused by these defines:

```
#define lt(a, b) (  ((a) <  -b) )
#define ge(a, b) (! ((a) <  -b) )
#define le(a, b) (  ((a) <=  b) )
#define gt(a, b) (! ((a) <=  b) )
#define eq(a, eps) ( (((a) <= eps) && !((a) < -eps)) )
#define ne(a, eps) ( !eq(a,eps) )
```

This is the error I get:

```
/Users/bs/util.h:284:22: note: expanded from macro 'eq'
#define eq(a, eps) ( (((a) <= eps) && !((a) < -eps)) )
                     ^
In file included from /Users/bs/geom.cc:35:
In file included from /Users/bs/coord.h:30:
In file included from /Users/bs/vronivector.h:6:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:38:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:216:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:15:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:678:12: error: 'inline' can
      only appear on functions
    static inline _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR bool eq(char_type __c1, char_type __c2) _NOEXCEPT
           ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/vroni.dir/geom.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/vroni.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What's the problem here, and can it be fixed?

Comment: [`std::char_traits::eq`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/cmp), macro has always been wrong.

Comment: out of interest why are you defining these macros, and why macros?

Comment: As I said, I have to deal with legacy code. In short: Very complex code but well tested code from mathematcial perspective, very stupid code from software perspective. I've actually rebased the whole project again just to get the legacy code working - an attempt to refactor caused too much of headache.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weird errors in stdc++ headers when trying to compile with clang++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969908/weird-errors-in-stdc-headers-when-trying-to-compile-with-clang)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a name conflict for the symbol 'eq'   Unfortunately c-style macros do a literal text replacement so the text associated with eq is being stuffed into the statement where you are seeing the error message which produces something like this:

```
static inline _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR bool  ( (((char_type __c1) <= eps) && !(char_type __c1) < -eps))  _NOEXCEPT
```

The best solution is to stop using macros and find another way to define your 'eq' 'lt' etc. functions.

You could, for example replace the eq macro with something like:

```
template<typename T>bool eq(T a,T eps) 
{
    return (a <= eps && a >= -eps);
}
```

A not-so-good solution would be to come up with a naming convention for your macros that is unlikely to conflict with symbols that will be used in other packages (for example you could name your macro EQ or EQ_ (Do not use leading underscores, that's a whole 'nother issue.)